# Android: quickblox incoming video call not receive

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, quickblox, videochat

I use `quickblox` for create video call

Start call work, but incoming service not work for opponent user

**VideoActivity**

```
public class VideoActivity extends E implements QBRTCClientSessionCallbacks,QBRTCClientVideoTracksCallbacks {

    private int userid;
    private Boolean isOutgoing,micE=true,vidE=true;
    private QBRTCSurfaceView surfaceView,remoteview;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private QBRTCSession currentsession;
    private QBMediaStreamManager mediaStreamManager;
    private ImageView mic,video;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video);
        userid=getIntent().getIntExtra("user", 1);
        userid = 39753771;
        isOutgoing=getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isoutgoing",false);
        isOutgoing = true;
        ProcessCalls();
        InitSignalling();
        if (isOutgoing) {
            //CallUser();
            SetCallerName(userid);
        }
        Log.i("errorCheck", "Nz: " + userid);
        Log.i("errorCheck", "Na: " + isOutgoing);
        if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("service",false)){
            Log.i("errorCheck", "x");
        }


        mic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mic);
        mic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (micE) {
                    micE = false;
                    AudioManage();
                } else {
                    micE = true;
                    AudioManage();
                }
            }
        });
        video=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.video);
        video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (vidE) {
                    vidE = false;
                    VideoManage();
                } else {
                    vidE = true;
                    VideoManage();
                }
            }
        });

        surfaceView =(QBRTCSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.localView);
        surfaceView.setMirror(true);
        surfaceView.requestLayout();

        remoteview=(QBRTCSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.opponentView);
        remoteview.requestLayout();
    }

    private void SetCallerName(Integer callerID) {
        TextView callerName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.callername);
        TextView callertime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.callTime);
        callerName.setText(callerID + " , You:");
        if(isOutgoing){
            callertime.setText("Calling...");
        }

    }

    private void InitSignalling() {
        final QBChatService chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();


                Log.i("errorCheck", "ERR1: " + G.userQB);
                chatService.login(G.userQB, new QBEntityCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Object result, Bundle params) {
                        Log.i("errorCheck", "R0: " + result);
                        Log.i("errorCheck", "R1: " + params);

                        chatService.getVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager().addSignalingManagerListener(new QBVideoChatSignalingManagerListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void signalingCreated(QBSignaling qbSignaling, boolean createdLocally) {
                                Log.i("errorCheck", "Q1: " + qbSignaling);
                                Log.i("errorCheck", "Q2: " + createdLocally);
                                if (!createdLocally) {
                                    QBRTCClient.getInstance(VideoActivity.this).addSignaling((QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        QBRTCClient.getInstance(G.currentActivity).addSessionCallbacksListener((QBRTCSessionEventsCallback) G.currentActivity);

                        QBRTCConfig.setDebugEnabled(true);
                        QBRTCClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).prepareToProcessCalls();

                        Log.i("errorCheck", "chatService1: " + chatService);
                        if(G.userMobile.equals("09139479548")) {
                            CallUser();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {
                        Log.i("errorCheck", "E1: " + errors);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void ProcessCalls() {
        QBRTCClient.getInstance(this).prepareToProcessCalls();
    }

    private void CallUser() {
        List<Integer> opponents = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        opponents.add(userid);

        Map<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
        userInfo.put("key", "value");

        QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType qbConferenceType = QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_VIDEO;
        QBRTCSession session = QBRTCClient.getInstance(G.currentActivity).createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponents, qbConferenceType);

        session.addVideoTrackCallbacksListener(this);

        session.startCall(userInfo);
        Log.i("errorCheck", "QR1: " + session);
        SetCallButtonsDialing(session,userInfo);
        StartDialRinging();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveNewSession(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
        Log.i("errorCheck","x");

        qbrtcSession.addVideoTrackCallbacksListener(this);
        Map<String,String> userInfo = qbrtcSession.getUserInfo();
        SetLayoutForReceiveCall(qbrtcSession,userInfo);
    }

    private void SetLayoutForReceiveCall(final QBRTCSession qbrtcSession,final Map<String, String> userInfo) {
        final FrameLayout receive=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.answerlayout);
        receive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        qbrtcSession.addVideoTrackCallbacksListener(this);
        final ImageView calll=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.answerCall);
        calll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Accept incoming call
                qbrtcSession.acceptCall(userInfo);
                receive.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                SetCallButtonsDialing(qbrtcSession, userInfo);
                StartTimer();
                if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.rejectcall).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                qbrtcSession.rejectCall(userInfo);
                VideoActivity.this.finish();
                if(mp!=null&&mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mp.stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onUserNoActions(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "no action by user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(mp!=null&&mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStartClose(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
        qbrtcSession.addVideoTrackCallbacksListener(this);
        try {
            qbrtcSession.getMediaStreamManager().setVideoCapturer(new QBRTCCameraVideoCapturer(this, null));
            mediaStreamManager = qbrtcSession.getMediaStreamManager();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserNotAnswer(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "No answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(mp!=null&&mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.stop();
        }
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallRejectByUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer, Map<String, String> map) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Call rejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(mp!=null&&mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.stop();
        }
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallAcceptByUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer, Map<String, String> map) {
        qbrtcSession.addVideoTrackCallbacksListener(this);
        if(mp!=null&&mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.stop();
        }
        StartTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveHangUpFromUser(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, Integer integer, Map<String, String> map) {
        if(mp!=null&&mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.stop();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Call ended by user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionClosed(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
        if(mp!=null&&mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocalVideoTrackReceive(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, QBRTCVideoTrack qbrtcVideoTrack) {
        Log.i("errorCheck", "WW1: " + qbrtcSession);
        qbrtcVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(surfaceView));
        surfaceView.setMirror(true);
        surfaceView.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoteVideoTrackReceive(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession, QBRTCVideoTrack qbrtcVideoTrack, Integer integer) {
        Log.i("errorCheck", "WW2: " + qbrtcSession);

        qbrtcVideoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(remoteview));
        mediaStreamManager = qbrtcSession.getMediaStreamManager();
        remoteview.requestLayout();
    }

    public void StartDialRinging(){
        try {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beep);
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**VideoCallService**

```
public class VideoCallService extends Service implements QBRTCClientSessionCallbacks {
    private Timer mTimer = null;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    public static final int notify = 300000;

    public VideoCallService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            Log.wtf("service", "start");

            if (mTimer != null) {
                Log.wtf("service", "All ready started");
            } else {
                mTimer = new Timer();   //recreate new
                mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplay(), 0, notify);
                LoginChatService();
                ProcessCalls();
                InitSignalling();
                QBRTCClient.getInstance(this).addSessionCallbacksListener(this);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.wtf("ex",""+e);
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void InitSignalling() {

        QBChatService.getInstance().getVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager()
                .addSignalingManagerListener(new QBVideoChatSignalingManagerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void signalingCreated(QBSignaling qbSignaling, boolean createdLocally) {
                        if (!createdLocally) {
                            QBRTCClient.getInstance(VideoCallService.this).addSignaling((QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    private void ProcessCalls() {
        QBRTCClient.getInstance(this).prepareToProcessCalls();
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceiveNewSession(QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
        //DataHolder.getInstance().setServiceData(qbrtcSession,qbrtcSession.getUserInfo());
        startActivity(new Intent(this,VideoActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).putExtra("service",true));
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".VideoCallService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.quickblox.sample.groupchatwebrtc" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".GcmPushListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.quickblox.messages.services.gcm.QBGcmPushInstanceIDService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data android:name="com.quickblox.messages.TYPE" android:value="GCM" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.quickblox.messages.SENDER_ID" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.quickblox.messages.QB_ENVIRONMENT" android:value="DEVELOPMENT" />
```

After start Call, session created for opponent

This my log for user caller

```
I/org.webrtc.Logging: SurfaceViewRenderer: localView: onMeasure(). New size: 200x200
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: localView: setLayoutAspectRatio: 1.0
I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: opponentView: setLayoutAspectRatio: 0.58536583
D/QBASDK: register network listener
D/QBASDK: Connected. Login to chat, currentUser JID: 39753009-65649, resource: android_ffffffff-ac04-0c2d-ffff-ffffd173e4c0
I/errorCheck: R0: null
I/errorCheck: R1: Bundle[{}]
D/RTCClient.:  Added session CALLBACK listenerapp.x.y.VideoActivity@4288e7f8
I/errorCheck: chatService1: com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService@42f6b478
D/RTCClient.: Call createNewSessionWithOpponents[39753771]conference type=QBConferenceType{value='1'}
D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession: Create new session
I/errorCheck: Q1: com.quickblox.chat.QBWebRTCSignaling@43156ce0
I/errorCheck: Q2: true
D/RTCClient.: New signalling was added for participant39753771
D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession: Make new channel for oppoennt:39753771com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBPeerChannel@42f23c00
D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession: isInitiator=true
D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession:  ADD VideoTrackCallbacksListener app.x.y.VideoActivity@4288e7f8
D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession: startCall
D/RTCClient.PeerFactoryManager: Creating Peer connection factory 
D/RTCClient.QBRTCSession.SessionWaitingTimers: Stop WaitTimer
```

But for opponent not set log ( not incoming notification or ... )

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android/issues/244). Check the [video-sample](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc). There is implementation of opening `IncomingCallFragment` by receiving push in this sample. Also, if you have successful subscription, but do not receive pushes, you always can check the following:

> 1. Check certificates for pushes: Admin panel ->Push Notification ->Settings -> APNS, GCM etc.
> 2. Send push from Admin Panel - > Push notifications - > Send ([link](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android#Send_Push_Notifications_from_Admin_panel))
> 3. Also you can check Push Notifications Queue tab in Admin panel, there should be a log of your push. It will help you to understand what's going on with your devices.

Hope this helps!